# ImportError: cannot import name 'LayoutLMv3Processor' from 'transformers' in sagemaker estimator

Tags: pytorch, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers

I am getting following error in huggingface sagemaker.

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'LayoutLMv3Processor' from 'transformers' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/transformers/__init__.py)
```

Here is the entrypoint

```
huggingface_estimator = HuggingFace(entry_point='train.py',
                            source_dir='./',
                            instance_type='ml.g5.xlarge',
                            instance_count=1,
                            role=role,
                            transformers_version='4.12',
                            pytorch_version='1.9',
                            py_version='py38',
                            hyperparameters = hyperparameters,
                            sagemaker_session=sess,
                                   
                                   )
```

Without the huggingface estimator, if I import this line in sagemaker, I did not get this error. The sagemaker version, I am using is `'2.118.0'`

Comment: Not clean when you say trying to import on SageMaker? Is that on notebook, if so have you tried installing the package?